# Solving mathematical summation

Tags: summation, summation-method

How to solve the following sum:

$$\sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{(1/2^n)^i \cdot (1 - 1/2^n)^{n-i}}{i!\cdot(n-i)!}$$

Comment: In the title, perhaps you want to change the word complex to something else.  The word complex often refers to "complex numbers," which is not what you are working with here.

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, is the $(n-i)!$ in the numerator or denominator (as written now, it appears to be in the numerator).

Comment: $\LaTeX$ hint:  to get multicharacter exponents like your (n-i) to render properly, enclose them in braces.  So 2^{(n-i)} gives $2^{(n-i)}$ while 2^(n-i) gives $2^(n-i)$  Thank you for working on this. It gets easier.

Answer (score 5):

After the rewrite of the question...
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{i!(n-i)!}\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)^i\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)^{n-i}
$$
can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)^i\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)^{n-i}.
$$
Then, by the binomial theorem, this is
$$
\frac{1}{n!}\left[\frac{1}{2^n}+\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\right]^n=\frac{1}{n!}
$$

Comment: question is updated, there is (n-i) in power of (1-1/2^n) in place of i.

Comment: Thus it is directly an application of binomial theorem as in the first answer of @Michael Burr... Next time, please, pay a particular attention to what you write...